# No consigo compartir de forma adecuada los volume que genero en docker-compose

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose

He creado un archivo docker-compose para poder crear los dos contenedores que necesito ahora mismo un contenedor mysql customizado y un contenedor wordpress. Intento crear volume y compartir carpetas para no perder los datos y poder modificar los archivos php.

El caso es que los dos volume se crean. Cuando hago un docker volume ls aparecen, pero no se comunican el contenedor y 'mi pc' a través de la carpeta compartida. No se descarga absolutamente nada en la carpeta. Es como si no existiese comunicación alguna.

Mi pc es un windows 10 pro, y los contenedores de docker los tengo en linux.

Archivo docker-compose:

```
version: '3.0'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:custom
     volumes:
       - c:\proyectos\bbdd:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: ****

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     volumes:
        - C:\proyectos\wordpress:/var/www/html
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ****
volumes:
```

Llevo unos pocos días trabajando con docker, no soy expert@.
Gracias por vuestro tiempo y ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

tenés que usar el path completo del host(tu pc) y el container.
Ej:

```
volumes:
       - <path_del_host>:<path_del_container>
```

Comment: Hola @Facundo Diaz Cobos. acabo de intentarlo de ese modo y no me da error, pero tampoco me comparte.

Comment: Es raro, estás seguro que la carpeta del host está vacia ?

Comment: Si estaba vacía. Al final me he descargado Kitematic para windows, y cuando haces click con el botón derecho en volumes te pregunta si lo quieres habilitar y me crea una carpeta en documentos dentro del usuario de la sesión, y ahí si me comparte. Esto como se podría hacer desde el cmd? Me gustaría no tener que depender del kitematic para esto.

Answer (score 0):

Echa un ojo a este fichero en github:

[Wordpress dentro de Docker compartiendo volumenes](https://github.com/p3drojimenez/docker-wordpress)

y a esta guia: https://pedrojimenez.info/docker/compose-wordpress/